# Adding ConversionService to Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Integration and String Cloud Stream. I have a header that I want my HTTP gateway to use, which has a Long value, but it can't convert from Long to String by default and so displays the error `Consider registering a Converter with ConversionService`.

Therefore I tried adding my own LongToStringConverter class and the following Bean so that LongToStringConverter can be used:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService()
{
  DefaultConversionService service = new DefaultConversionService();
  service.addConverter( new LongToStringConverter() );
  return service;
}
```

Then then received the following error: `Dispatcher has no subscribers`.

If I only return an instance of `DefaultConversionService` from the above bean I still receive the error.

When I remove the above bean and instead simply convert the Long value to String when setting the header value and that works without errors. Is it possible to use ConversionService instead? If so then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there *is* already a `ConversionService`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#payload-type-conversion. And it has some set of predefined converters. So, you should consider to use `@IntegrationConverter` on the matter.

On the other hand it is unclear why do you need to do that at all. I wonder why `Long.toString()` isn't enough for you when you declare that header in first place.